# Reduce method not running in mongodb mapreduce

Tags: node.js, mongodb, scope, mapreduce

I need to use a temporary variable to store values temporarily inside the reduce function. On my output log, the result says that the number of times the reduce function ran is 0. It however runs once I perform other type of calculations.

The reduce function is not able to access the **prev** objects when I execute the code. If it is of any help, I am using mongojs library for nodejs.

```
var  map = function() {
        emit(this._id,
             {
             d1: this.day_chan1,
             d2: this.day_chan2,
             d3: this.day_chan3
           });
    };       

var reduce = function(key, values) {

                       var data = {};

                       var curr = values[0];

                       data.d1 =  curr.d1 - prev.d1;
                       data.d2 =  curr.d2 - prev.d2;
                       data.d3 =  curr.d3 - prev.d3;

                       prev = curr;

                       return { timestamp: key , data: data };

        };

var prev = { d1: 0, d2: 0, d3: 0 };

this
    .db
    .mapReduce(
                  map,
                          reduce,                                                 
                          {  
                           scope: { prev : prev },
                           sort: { timestamp: 1 },
                             query: {},
                             out: 'temp'                                                  
                            }
                         ,
                         function (err, data) {                                        
                            if(err) callback(err);
                            else callback(data);
                         });
```

This is a sample of the data that I am processing

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5650845744aeea3dba90326d"), 
    "timestamp" : "2015-09-21 05:02:52", 
    "curr_property" : NumberInt(1818), 
    "curr_property_cost" : NumberInt(21), 
    "day_property" : NumberInt(30), 
    "day_property_cost" : NumberInt(18), 
    "curr_solar_generating" : NumberInt(676), 
    "curr_solar_export" : NumberInt(0), 
    "day_solar_generated" : NumberInt(11), 
    "day_solar_export" : NumberInt(0), 
    "curr_chan1" : NumberInt(676), 
    "curr_chan2" : NumberInt(676), 
    "curr_chan3" : NumberInt(466), 
    "day_chan1" : NumberInt(11), 
    "day_chan2" : NumberInt(11), 
    "day_chan3" : NumberInt(7), 
    "gatewayId" : 23.0
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5650845744aeea3dba90326e"), 
    "timestamp" : "2015-09-21 05:03:52", 
    "curr_property" : NumberInt(1818), 
    "curr_property_cost" : NumberInt(21), 
    "day_property" : NumberInt(60), 
    "day_property_cost" : NumberInt(18), 
    "curr_solar_generating" : NumberInt(676), 
    "curr_solar_export" : NumberInt(0), 
    "day_solar_generated" : NumberInt(22), 
    "day_solar_export" : NumberInt(0), 
    "curr_chan1" : NumberInt(676), 
    "curr_chan2" : NumberInt(676), 
    "curr_chan3" : NumberInt(466), 
    "day_chan1" : NumberInt(22), 
    "day_chan2" : NumberInt(22), 
    "day_chan3" : NumberInt(15), 
    "gatewayId" : 23.0
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5650845744aeea3dba90326f"), 
    "timestamp" : "2015-09-21 05:04:52", 
    "curr_property" : NumberInt(1818), 
    "curr_property_cost" : NumberInt(21), 
    "day_property" : NumberInt(91), 
    "day_property_cost" : NumberInt(19), 
    "curr_solar_generating" : NumberInt(676), 
    "curr_solar_export" : NumberInt(0), 
    "day_solar_generated" : NumberInt(33), 
    "day_solar_export" : NumberInt(0), 
    "curr_chan1" : NumberInt(676), 
    "curr_chan2" : NumberInt(676), 
    "curr_chan3" : NumberInt(466), 
    "day_chan1" : NumberInt(33), 
    "day_chan2" : NumberInt(33), 
    "day_chan3" : NumberInt(23), 
    "gatewayId" : 23.0
}
```

and this is the output on my log

```
{
    "result" : "temp",
    "timeMillis" : 3362,
    "counts" : {
        "input" : 39781,
        "emit" : 39781,
        "reduce" : 0,
        "output" : 39781
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

This is how the temp collection looks after the operation

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5650845744aeea3dba90326d"), 
    "value" : {
        "d1" : 11.0, 
        "d2" : 11.0, 
        "d3" : 7.0
    }
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5650845744aeea3dba90326e"), 
    "value" : {
        "d1" : 22.0, 
        "d2" : 22.0, 
        "d3" : 15.0
    }
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5650845744aeea3dba90326f"), 
    "value" : {
        "d1" : 33.0, 
        "d2" : 33.0, 
        "d3" : 23.0
    }
}
```

Here is what I was hoping to get

```
    { 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5650845744aeea3dba90326d"), 
    "value" : {
        "d1" : 0, 
        "d2" : 0, 
        "d3" : 0
    }
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5650845744aeea3dba90326e"), 
    "value" : {
        "d1" : 11.0, 
        "d2" : 11.0, 
        "d3" : 9.0
    }
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5650845744aeea3dba90326f"), 
    "value" : {
        "d1" : 11.0, 
        "d2" : 11.0, 
        "d3" : 18.0
    }
}
```

I am banging out my head on this one and would really appreciate some help.

UPDATE:

The code is currently running inside a service method in mongojs. Here is it's equivalent in the mongo console.

```
db.testdb.mapReduce(map,
                    reduce,                                               
                    {  
                           scope: { prev : prev },
                           sort: { timestamp: 1 },
                             query: {},
                             out: 'temp'                                                  
                    });
```

the declarations for map and reduce methods are the same as the one at the top.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show us the following three elements that may increase chances of you getting correct answers; some sample documents, the actual output and your expected results?

Comment: @chridam Just updated it.

Comment: Can you place prev above the reduce function ?

Comment: @Ravenous I have done that already. I still get the same result

Comment: I need more context. It looks like all of this code is inside another function? How is that patent function being called, when and where? What's its scope?

Comment: @Ravenous updated, have a look

Comment: @Bazinga777 so although your map function can do what it wants and emit what it wants, i'm interpreting the mapreduce capability to one thing. "MongoDB will not call the reduce function for a key that has only a single value. The values argument is an array whose elements are the value objects that are “mapped” to the key." https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/#mapreduce-map-cmd

Comment: @ravenous you should add that as an answer. I was having this exact problem and that was the issue in my case.

Answer (score 0):

@Bazinga777 so although your map function can do what it wants and emit what it wants, i'm interpreting the mapreduce capability to one thing. "MongoDB will not call the reduce function for a key that has only a single value. The values argument is an array whose elements are the value objects that are “mapped” to the key." https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/#mapreduce-map-cmd